# Questions about C code and Pollard's rho algorithm for logarithms

Tags: c, discrete-mathematics, logarithm

This code is written by C from pollard's rho algorithm for logarithms(from wiki). In this code, if i put alpha=2, beta=5, N=1019, it have to return a=681, b=378, A=301, B=426 and X=1019. But I run it, I only get right X=1019, and I get (a,b,A,B)=(672,367,445,706). Do you know what the problem is?

[wiki site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms/)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int alpha, beta, N;

void xab(int *x, int *a, int *b)
{
    switch(*x%3){
    case 0: *x=((*x)*(*x))%N;   *a=((*a)*2)%N;  *b=((*b)*2)%N;  break;
    case 1: *x=(alpha*(*x))%N;  *a=((*a)+1)%N;  break;
    case 2: *x=(beta*(*x))%N;   *b=((*b)+1)%N;  break;
    } 
}  

int main(void)
{    
    int x=1;    int a=0;    int b=0;
    int X=1;    int A=0;    int B=0;
    int i;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &alpha, &beta, &N);    

for(i=1;i<N;i++){
        printf("Code #%d\n", i);
        xab(&x,&a,&b);
        printf("x=%d a=%d b=%d\n", x, a, b);    
        xab(&X,&A,&B);  xab(&X,&A,&B);
        printf("X=%d A=%d B=%d\n\n", X, A, B);
        if(x==X) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't copy the `new_xab` function correctly.  Note that the `new_xab` function uses both `N` and `n` where `N=1019` and `n=1018`.  For reference, here are three lines from the Wikipedia article

```
case 0: x = x*x     % N;  a =  a*2  % n;  b =  b*2  % n;  break;
case 1: x = x*alpha % N;  a = (a+1) % n;                  break;
case 2: x = x*beta  % N;                  b = (b+1) % n;  break;
```